# Dynamic link_to path with params[:controller]: Brakeman Dangerous Send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, brakeman

I have the following partial `_filters.html.haml` which has been used many times in my code:

```
- resource ||= params[:controller]
= link_to send("delete_#{resource}_path"), method: :delete, data: { confirm: delete_confirmation } do
   = fa_icon delete_icon, class: 'm-r-quarter', text: delete_text
```

It has a dynamic delete path constructed from params[:controller].
Brakeman gives the following error message for the above code:

```
Confidence: High
Category: Dangerous Send
Check: Send
Message: User controlled method execution
Code: send("delete_#{params[:controller]}_path")
```

Is this a valid error shown by Brakeman? I know that whitelisting the params is one solution to avoid dangerous send. Is there any better way of resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't actually allow user controlled method execution since `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]` are set by the Rails router and will override any user provided values.

It is very stinky though. A slight improvement would be to use the `controller_name` helper method:

```
= link_to send("delete_#{controller_name}_path"), ...
```

But it really begs the question why on earth you inflicted this monstrosity on yourself to begin with. What is this even supposed to do since its missing an id - destroy everything?

If you want to destroy a resource in Rails you send a DELETE request to the member path:

```
DELETE /things/1
```

Since there is no silly prefix in the URL you can just generate it with:

```
= link_to(model_instance, method: :destroy) do
  = fa_icon delete_icon, class: 'm-r-quarter', text: delete_text
```

If you really do need to generate a path dynamically use [the polymorphic route helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) instead of send:

```
= link_to [:delete, controller_name], method: :delete, data: { confirm: delete_confirmation } do
  = fa_icon delete_icon, class: 'm-r-quarter', text: delete_text
```

Comment: Yes, it's for bulk delete